# Cannot implement Queue - does not override abstract method offer(java.lang.Object)

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the Java 1.6 Queue interface, but I am getting the error:

**MyBoundedQueue.java:27: MyBoundedQueue is not abstract and does not override abstract method offer(java.lang.Object) in java.util.Queue**

What I really don't understand is that there is no **offer(Object)** method in the Queue class. The [Java 1.6 API for Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) says there is a method **boolean offer(E e)**, where E is a parameterized type, and indeed, I have implemented that, as shown below.

Any help?

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MyBoundedQueue<ItemType> implements Queue
{
    private int _maxSize;
    private ArrayDeque<ItemType> _window;

    public MyBoundedQueue(int maxSize)
    {
        _maxSize = maxSize;
        _window = new ArrayDeque<ItemType>(_maxSize);
    }

    public boolean add(ItemType item)
    {
        if (_window.size() >=  _maxSize)
        {
            _window.removeFirst();
        }

        _window.addLast(item);
    }

    public ItemType element()
    {
        return _window.element();
    }

    public boolean offer(ItemType item)
    {
        add(item);
        return true;
    }

    public ItemType peek()
    {
        return _window.peek();
    }

    public ItemType poll()
    {
        return _window.poll();
    }

    public ItemType remove()
    {
        return _window.remove();
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        _window.clear();
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return _window.size();
    }

    public Iterator<ItemType> iterator()
    {
        return _window.iterator();
    }


}
```

Comment: Convention is to keep parameter types as single uppercase letters so that they are easily distinguished from actual class types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to:

```
public class MyBoundedQueue implements Queue<ItemType>
```

It's telling you `offer(Object)` because without the Generic typing that's what it would be. You also don't need to specify a generic type for your class ... you're not using generic types anywhere.

If you wanted your class to use generics you'd want to do:

```
public class MyBoundedQueue<T> implements Queue<T> {
...
```

And everywhere you currently have `ItemType` you'd use `T` instead.

Comment: Thanks. The class does indeed use generics. I'm coming from C++ STL, which may or may not have the convention of using a single upper-case character as the type. :P

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 - I have to swap c++ out when I'm working with Java. The two are close enough to ruin your day after you sit staring at some thing yelling "Why won't you compile" at the screen :-D

Answer (score 2):

1. Please stick to coding conventions and use a single, upper-case letter for type parameters!
2. You'll need to implement `Queue<T>` (or `Queue<ItemType>` if you insist)

Comment: You have taught me a wise lesson in coding conventions today, dty :D

Answer (score 2):

Change to

`MyBoundedQueue implements Queue<ItemType>`

Your code is equivalent to

`MyBoundedQueue implements Queue<Object>`

Answer (score 2):

Is `ItemType` a fixed class, or is it supposed to be a parameter?

If it's fixed, it should be `class MyBoundedDeque implements Queue<ItemType>`, not the other way around.

Otherwise, it should be `class MyBoundedQueue<ItemType> implements Queue<ItemType>`.

Comment: @OP: And this is exactly why we have coding conventions - nobody knows whether you're using `ItemType` as a type parameter, or if it's a class that you're tying to supply as an argument to the Queue's type parameter.